# Unable to run azure command line

Tags: python, azure

I have successfully installed the Azure Command line. Also, python is installed on the server. However, when I run /usr/bin/az command it gives error as follows:

`Could not import runpy module`

The output for python version is as follows:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2018, 04:38:38) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: You should open an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing generally comes into the picture whenever there's a broken python environment on the host. In most cases, the fix is to re-install the package, but for the Azure CLI, you will have to make some other arrangements. I solved the issue by using the following method:

Step 1: Find the location of your AZ using `which az` most likely it should be sitting in `/usr/bin/`. 

Step 2: Take a copy of your existing `az` and copy it to let's say `az_copy` 
Step 3: Edit the `az` file using any of the available editors and replace with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#/usr/lib64/az/bin/python -Esm azure.cli "$@"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib64/az/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib64/az/lib/python2.7/site-packages

/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python2.7 -sm azure.cli "$@"

# -E     : ignore PYTHON* environment variables (such as PYTHONPATH)
# -s     : don't add user site directory to sys.path; also PYTHONNOUSERSITE
```

Post this, save and execute az, it should work. 
Do let me know if that worked out for you.